Homomorphic product of graphs
I was looking into how the eigenvectors of graphs change upon taking products. For instance, the cartesian product of two graphs $G_1 \square G_2$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_i + \mu_j$ for $\lambda_i$ some eigenvalue of $G_1$ and $\mu_j$ some eigenvalue of $G_2$. Similar remarks can be made for the direct product $G_1 \otimes G_2$ or the strong product $G_1 \boxtimes G_2$.
With that, I was curious about a different product I found, the homomorphic product. We consider two graphs, $G$ and $H$. Then the homomorphic product $G \ltimes H$ is given by vertex set $V(G) \times V(H)$ with vertices $(a,x) \sim (b,y)$ if $a = b$ or $a \sim b$ and $x \not\sim y$.
I was curious on what the eigenvalues of this product would look like in terms of the eigenvalues of $G$ and $H$, and perhaps how to go about determining them.

Are you talking about eigenvectors on adjacency matrix or Laplacian?

@caduk i'm talking about eigenvectors / values on the adjacency matrix
